# passing parameters via function

Tags: c#

I'm making a C# airlines reservation project, taking the user details via form1, say I have a class `PassengerDetails` with class variables. Now, on click of the button, I need to assign all those `TextBox` values to the class variables

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fn = txtFname.Text;
    string ln = txtLname.Text;
    string add = txtAddress.Text;
    int age =   int.Parse(txtAge.Text);
    submit(fn, ln, add, age);
}
```

I need to pass these to the function. How should I declare it?

Comment: Please use better variable names. `fn` and `ln` don't say much, and `add` is plain misleading. What's wrong with `firstname`, `lastname` and `address`? Intellisense will type it for you after the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class for passenger data and pass this as a parameter.

```
class Passenger
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var passenger = new Passenger
                        {
                            FirstName = txtFname.Text,
                            LastName = txtLname.Text,
                            Address = txtAdd.Text,
                            Age = int.Parse(txtAge.Text)
                        };
    AddPassenger(passenger);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make a simple assignment?

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string fn;
  public string ln;
 public string add;
  public int age;
}
```

the submit function is

```
submit(string fn, string ln, string add, int age)
{
  MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
  myclass.fn = fn;
  myclass.ln = ln;
  myclass.add=add;
  mycalss.age = age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have a form-level variable that stores an instance of your passenger details class can call that:

**Note: pseudo code!  Do not copy and paste!**

```
class form1()
{
    private passenger_details = new PassengerDetail()

    private void button_click()
    {
        passenger_details.age = int(nameField.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also overload your constructor:

```
class Passenger
{
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }

     void Passenger() {}

     void Passenger(string _firstName, string _lastName, string _address, int _age) 
     {
          this.FirstName = _firstName;
          this.LastName = _lastName;
          this.Address = _address;
          this.Age = _age; 
     }
}
```

Then your event would just assign them at creation. (following code assumes you have a global variable called MyPassenger)

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    this.MyPassenger = new Passenger(txtFname.Text, txtLname.Text, txtAddress.Text, int.Parse(txtAge.Text));     

}
```